# Valor de Textbox criado dinamicamente na Page da Multipage (que também é criada dinamicamente) não se matém quando muda de Page

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa Noite,

Estou fazendo um controle no excel, no codigo há criação automatica de Pages e também de controles, como o TextBox, criados dinamicamente dentro dessas Pages.
A Page 1 já vem os controles já colocados, eu só copio e colo nas outras Pages que serão inseridas automaticamente.
Porém o valor dos outros controles nas outras Pages não se conserva.
Nas fotos abaixo, tem-se a pagina 1 e 2, perceb-se que a ifnormação da pagina 1 não vai para pagina 2 e isto está correto, é isso que eu quero, **informações diferentes em cada pagina.**
Porém, ao colocar informação na Page 2 (ou em qualquer outra Page que não seja a Page 1) essa informação não fica no textbox, ou seja simplemente some.

**Obs:** Essas páginas são criadas por meio do SpinButton, onde ao crescer a quantidade, adciona paginas e ao apertar para baixo do spin, remove as paginas. E as paginas criadas são baseadas no valor da caixa de texto, onde o valor do spinbutton é referenciado.

**Código abaixo:**

```
*- Evento change da Page* 

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
    Dim varA As Integer
    Dim clt As Control
    varA = Me.MultiPage1.Value
    var = Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
    
       MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Copy
    If varA > 0 Then
         
             With MultiPage1.Pages(varA)
             .Paste
             For Each ctl In .Controls
              Select Case TypeName(ctl)

                    Case "TextBox": ctl.Value = ""

              End Select
           Next ctl
           End With
    End If
end sub

*-Evento do SpinButton* 

Private Sub DPNs_SpinDown()
    Dim pag As Page
    Dim var As Integer
    var = Me.DPNs.Value
    varA = MultiPage1.Pages.Count
          MultiPage1.Pages.Remove var
       If var = 0 Then
      
         MultiPage1.Pages.Remove var
        MultiPage1.Pages.Controls.Remove
         End If

    If varA < 0 Then

        MsgBox ("Paginas Removidas com Sucesso")

End If

    
    
   
        
       
End Sub

Private Sub DPNs_SpinUp()
  
     MultiPage1.Pages.Add ("PartNumber" & DPNs.Value + 1)
         
End Sub

*-Código da Caixa de texto ao lado do SppinButton* 


Private Sub QtdPN_Change()
Dim NovaVar As Integer

        NovaVar = Val(QtdPN.Text)
        If NovaVar >= DPNs.Min And NovaVar <= DPNs.Max Then
        DPNs.Value = NovaVar
        End If

End Sub

*- Codigo Change SpinButton* 
Private Sub DPNs_Change()

QtdPN.Text = DPNs.Value


End Sub
```

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: SpinButton e Quantidade de pages]

Answer (score 0):

Esse código está adicionando TextBoxes a cada seleção de página que o usuário faz. Então, se a Page for selecionada, por exemplo, 3 vezes, haverá um total de 3 * o número de TextBoxes em Pages(0), resultado das colagens realizadas a cada ativação.

Para resolver isto, elaborei uma rotina em que a criação e eliminação de Pages do MultiPage são feitas adequadamente no evento do SpinButton. Adapte o código à sua realidade.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DPNs_SpinDown()
'excluir page do Multipage1
    If MultiPage1.Pages.Count > 1 Then    'não é possível excluir a única página existente
        MultiPage1.Pages.Remove Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1
    End If
    Me.QtdPN = DPNs.Value
End Sub

Private Sub DPNs_SpinUp()
'adicionar page ao Multipage1
    Dim oPage As MSForms.Page
    Dim CTL As MSForms.Control
    Dim intPageCount As Integer

    intPageCount = MultiPage1.Pages.Count    'inicia em 1

    MultiPage1.Pages.Add ("PartNumber" & intPageCount)
    Set oPage = MultiPage1.Pages(MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1)
    MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Copy
    oPage.Paste
    For Each CTL In oPage.Controls
        If TypeName(CTL) = "TextBox" Then
            CTL.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
    Me.QtdPN = Me.DPNs.Value
End Sub
```